# batch-import binary download works for nodes, not relationships

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing

I used Michael Hunger's batch-import to successfully import a test node file that looks like this:

```
NPI:int:providers   EntityType  City    State
1   Individual  New York    NY
2   Organization    Philadelphia    PA
3   Individual  Reno    NV  
4   Individual  Saratoga    NY
```

My test edge file uses indexing of inserted properties. It looks something like this:

```
NPI:int:providers NPI:int:providers type    
1   2   REFERRED_TO
1   3   REFERRED_TO
1   4   REFERRED_TO
2   3   REFERRED_TO
3   4   REFERRED_TO
```

Per the instructions I added

```
 batch_import.node_index.providers=exact
 batch_import.relationship_index.providers=exact
```

To my batch.properties file. However, when I try to import my relationship file, there is an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.lookup(Importer.java:13
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.id(Importer.java:183)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Imp
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:83)
```

The actual dataset contains about 4 mil nodes and 150 mil relationships indexed in the manner of the test file, so changing the indexing is not feasible. I am on Neo4j 2.0.4.

Comment: How do you run the import command?

Comment: you don't need that: batch_import.relationship_index.providers=exact, actually this can cause an issue